# React Native: Horizontal and Vertical Paging Together

Tags: android, css, react-native

Currently trying to implement https://github.com/leecade/react-native-swiper with my program. Following his example, I tried vertical paging by rotating the element by 90 degrees and the children 90 degrees back.

Though it works, it's quite buggy where I'm only able to swipe left and right only on the edge of the screens. Ideally I want to be able to swipe in any direction on the screen. As well as preventing my up and down page from swiping horizontally.

Horizontal component

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {
    AppRegistry,
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    View,
    ScrollView
} from 'react-native';
import {Parallax2} from "./Parallax2";

import Swiper from 'react-native-swiper';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    wrapper: {
    },
    slide1: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#9DD6EB',
    },
    slide2: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#97CAE5',
    },
    slide3: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#92BBD9',
    },
    text: {
        color: '#fff',
        fontSize: 30,
        fontWeight: 'bold',
    },
})

export class Parallax extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View
                style={{flex: 1}}>
                <Swiper
                    style={styles.wrapper}
                    showsButtons={false}
                    loop={false}
                    showsPagination={false}
                    index={1}>
                    <View
                        style={styles.slide1}>
                        <Text style={styles.text}>Left</Text>
                    </View>
                    <Parallax2/>
                    <View
                        style={styles.slide3}>
                        <Text
                            style={styles.text}>Right</Text>
                    </View>
                </Swiper>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Vertical component, almost the same file, just in the styles I added: `transform: [{rotate: "90deg"}]` to the wrapper, and `transform: [{rotate: "-90deg"}]` to the corresponding slides.

For example:

```
wrapper: {
    transform: [{rotate: "90deg"}]
}
```

And -90 would be added to slide 1, 2, and 3

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {
    AppRegistry,
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    View,
    ScrollView
} from 'react-native';

import Swiper from 'react-native-swiper';

export class Parallax2 extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View
                style={{flex: 1}}>
                <Swiper
                    style={styles.wrapper}
                    showsButtons={false}
                    loop={false}
                    showsPagination={false}
                    index={1}>
                    <View
                        style={styles.slide1}>
                        <Text
                            style={styles.text}>Up</Text>
                    </View>
                    <View
                        style={styles.slide2}>
                        <Text
                            style={styles.text}>Index</Text>
                    </View>
                    <View
                        style={styles.slide3}>
                        <Text
                            style={styles.text}>Down</Text>
                    </View>
                </Swiper>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see that there are no responses for this issue. I really recommend a walkaround by getting things done by the swiping direction on the screen. A great package for doing this is https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-swipe-gestures

You can go around the different screens the way you want very easily, just look at the code example provided in the documentation.

Comment: This answer would be better if you put the code example in the body of your answer in case the link ever becomes dead in the future.